# Outlook API email attachment issue

Tags: python, rest, email, outlook, outlook-api

I am trying to use Outlook's REST API in my python code to send an email in behalf of a user who already gives me his consent.

I was able to successfully send text emails using their /me/sendmail node with the following payload:

```
    email_payload = {
        "Message": {
            "Subject": email_subject,
            "Body": {
                "ContentType": "Text",
                "Content": email_body
            },
            "ToRecipients": [
                {
                    "EmailAddress": {
                        "Address": to
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

However, when trying to add attachments (based on their documentation), I encounter some issues:

```
        email_payload["Message"]["Attachments"] = [
            {
                "ContentType": "application/pdf",
                "Name": "{0}".format("something.pdf"),
                "ContentBytes": base64.b64encode(attachment.read())
            }
        ]
```

Issues consist in 415 response status code with the following content:
{u'error': {u'message': u'A missing or empty content type header was found when trying to read a message. The content type header is required.', u'code': u'RequestBodyRead'}}

Couldn't find anything regarding this in their documentation. Hope somebody can enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having such issues, here's the context and fix:

Initially, since I was sending only plain-text emails, my request header looked like this:

```
request_headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer {0}".format(token),
}
```

And the actual request:

```
    api_response = requests.post(
        request_url,
        json.dumps(body),
        headers=request_headers
    )
```

As you might have noticed I wasn't sending any content-type in my headers (not sure why), but everything went well so far up until when I decided to add attachments too.

Seems like if my request_headers would contain Content-Type too, everything would go well:

```
  request_headers = {
             'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(refreshed_token),
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }
```